# How to useReact native Ii18 for language change?

Tags: react-native

I am using this package for React native

```
import I18n, { getLanguages } from 'react-native-i18n';
import en from './locales/en';
import ara from './locales/ara';

I18n.fallbacks = true;

I18n.translations = {
    en,
    ara
};

export default I18n;
```

But the problem is I am not not able to rerender my app data as the language change with this

I18n.locale = 'en';

But component not changing the text change. Also I want to know that how can I create en.json, ara.json files automatically for language change.

Or I have to create each key for each language. Please check and provide me solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest example for creating multi-language apps with the i18n library.

https://betterprogramming.pub/creating-a-multi-language-app-in-react-native-9828b138c274

It will also guide you on how to use language-specific JSON files.

Steps to make a multi-language app:

1. Create a file as follows with uses React Context API

**LanguageContext.js**

```html
import React, { createContext, useContext } from "react";
import {
    I18nManager,
  } from "react-native";
import i18n from "i18n-js";
import memoize from "lodash.memoize"; // Use for caching/memoize for better performance

const LanguageContext = createContext();

const translationGetters = {
    // lazy requires (metro bundler does not support symlinks)
    en: () => require("../translations/en.json"),
    fr: () => require("../translations/fr.json")
};

const translate = memoize(
    (key, config) => i18n.t(key, config),
    (key, config) => (config ? key + JSON.stringify(config) : key)
);

const setI18nConfig = (languageTag = 'en', isRTL = false) => {
    // clear translation cache
    translate.cache.clear();

    // update layout direction
    I18nManager.forceRTL(isRTL);

    // set i18n-js config
    i18n.translations = { [languageTag]: translationGetters[languageTag]() };
    i18n.locale = languageTag;
};

export const languageContext = () => useContext(LanguageContext);

export const LanguageConsumer = LanguageContext.Consumer;

export class LanguageProvider extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            languageTag: 'en',
            isRTL: false
        }
        setI18nConfig(); // set initial config
    }
    
    handleLocalizationChange = (languageObj = this.props.languageState) => {
        const {languageTag, isRTL} = languageObj;
        setI18nConfig(languageTag, isRTL);
        this.setState(languageObj)
        this.forceUpdate();
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.handleLocalizationChange(this.props.languageState)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <LanguageContext.Provider
                value={{
                    translate,
                    handleLocalizationChange: this.handleLocalizationChange
                }}>
                {this.props.children}
            </LanguageContext.Provider>
        );
    }
};
```

2. Import the above-created file in your root component like App.js

**App.js File**

```html
import React from 'react';
import {LanguageProvider} from './LanguageContent';

const App = (props) => {
  return (
    <LanguageProvider>
      <MainNavigation />
    </LanguageProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

3. Now use the context in any of your app child screens like as below:

**MainNavigation.js File**

```html
import React from 'react';
import { languageContext } from "./LanguageContent";

const MainNavigation = () => {

    const {translate, handleLocalizationChange} = languageContext();
    
    const onLanguageChangeHandler = () => {
        handleLocalizationChange({languageTag: 'fr', isRTL: false})
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{translate('Hello')}</Text>
            <Pressable
             onPress={onLanguageChangeHandler}
            >
                <Text>{"Change Language"}</Text>
            </Pressable>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: this is very old approach

Comment: @PuneetKansal May be

Comment: what is your use case like are you allowing to change the language at run time or set the app language at initially startup ?

Comment: I am changing.  I18n.locale = 'en' using this on buttons.

Comment: @PuneetKansal, I have updated my answer please have a look

Comment: okay @jignesh your code is fine. But I wanted to know why this is not rerending the data on use this. i18n.t("key")

Comment: You do have to implement some extra steps like component forceUpdate or more than that I can clear after your code review.

Comment: also I have create json file for each language manually or I can create a automatically Jignesh

Comment: No, you do have to create json file manually for those literals that are being used by you app

Comment: How it will created automatically then.

Comment: [missing "en.greetding" translation]

Comment: We must have to create it manually there it no way to create it automatically

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an automatically translate i18n, you will have to use a service like **Google Translate API**, here are some packages that portray and consume a similar approach.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18next-google-translate

https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n-auto-translate